# Is there a way to drop the comma and space elements when using Date.FormatStyle?

Tags: ios, swift5, dateformatter

If you

```
let s = d!.formatted(
    Date.FormatStyle()
        .year(.twoDigits)
        .month(.twoDigits)
        .day(.twoDigits)
        .hour(.defaultDigits(amPM: .narrow))
        .minute(.twoDigits))
print(s)
```

the result is like ...

```
11/03/23, 11:30 a
10/07/23, 6:00 p
```

naturally I need a slightly different format ...

```
11/20/23 11:20a
10/17/23 2:00p
```

Does FormatStyle have the ability to alter the comma and the day period space?